# Closed as "exact duplicate" without stating what the duplicate was

Tags: bug, status-norepro, closed-questions

This question: [Why an empty Java app consumes memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655391/why-an-empty-java-app-consumes-memory)

Comment: The first line of the question links to the duplicate. "Possible Duplicate:
Why does an empty Java program consume memory?" So what's your problem?

Comment: @CodeInChaos Let me guess, he missed it, and only read the close reason?

Comment: Next time screenshot to prove your point otherwise people won't believe you.

Answer (score 5):

It's written in at the top of the question by the community user.  Admittedly it's hard to see because of the similarity to the code block but it has been put in nonetheless.

[image: Screenshot of link]

It is also possible to see the duplicate text being added in the [edits of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9655391/revisions)

Comment: That was edited in AFTER the post was closed (and, I think, after my post here), and no prior comment mentioned it.

Comment: @TheDarkAvenger Community added the note at [14.06](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9655391/timeline) **immediately** after the question was closed.  Your meta question was asked at [14.35](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/125273/timeline) as seen in timeline views.  Possibly you just didn't notice it?

Comment: @The: You do have to refresh the page in order to see the update.